# How to implement a lightmap

Tags: xna, c#

I saw [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/56502/42731) answer and I got what he has done, but how do I create a lightmap same as [this](http://playstarbound.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Dungeon.jpg) one?

thanks in advance!

(from what lightmap should be built from (array?) and how do I calculate a lightmap like this?)

Comment: That answer you looked as provides all the information you need to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific about what you've tried and what about it didn't work? Right now it seems you're just having trouble implementing the answers provided in the other question. Remember that this isn't a discussion site, so you need to ask a specific question about a specific narrowly scoped problem. I can re-open this question if you provided more specifics about how your question is different.